# Rotating Triangle causes black screen?

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, sfml

I'm trying to rotate a 2D triangle in OpenGL and SFML but for some reason I'm getting a black screen. Without the rotation bit, the code works fine and displays a 2D triangle like it should, so I know it's the rotation code causing the black screen.

Here's my code:

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

int drawTri()
{
GLfloat rtri;
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -6.0f);

glRotatef(rtri, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0, 0.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glEnd();

glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -6.0f);

rtri+=0.2f;

return 0;
}

int main()
{
sf::WindowSettings winSet;
winSet.DepthBits = 24;
winSet.StencilBits = 8;
winSet.AntialiasingLevel = 2;
sf::Window App(sf::VideoMode(640, 480, 32), "Practice", sf::Style::Close, winSet);


bool isRunning = true;

while(App.IsOpened())
{
    sf::Event aEvent;
    if(App.GetEvent(aEvent))
        if(aEvent.Type == sf::Event::Closed) 
        isRunning = false;

    drawTri();

    if(!isRunning)
        App.Close();

    App.Display();
}
}
```

[here's](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/rotation/14001/) the tutorial I'm learning from.

I don't think I need the headers at the top of the tutorial code, but I'm new so I could be wrong.

Comment: Using glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -6.0f); you moving your triangle SIX UNITS in -z direction, which is actually in this case, with default view and projection matrices, is SEVERAL SCREENS out of view!

Comment: and i think you miss at least one glMatrixMode here

Comment: I thought glMatrixMode was only when dealing with 3D objects :/ oops.

Comment: And having it set -6 in the Z isn't the problem, or at least shouldn't be as it was like that before I tried adding the rotate and it displayed the triangle just fine.

Comment: i don't see where you initialize rtri variable, so it's value is complete garbage

Comment: Above glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

Comment: this is not initialization, if you don't set a specific value, it will be garbage

Comment: Ok but adding a initial value to it doesn't make it work, I wont to know why it isn't working and how I can fix it :/

Comment: i would still suggest you to remove glTranslate call(or replace with smaller values), as i think that it does moves you way out of the visible space.

Comment: Ok so now it's displaying the triangle again, but it doesn't rotate.

Comment: why should it rotate? Your rtri variable will always have the same value when glRotatef is executed.
I would suggest you to study language(C++) first before attempting to do anything with OpenGL. Or you will make a lot of newbie mistakes in both fields, which is just hard.

Comment: declare rtri as static, you can refer to wiki here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable

Answer (score 0):

You first glTranslate and then glRotate, so your camera is not looking at the triangle.
You should first rotate (the triangle) and then translate backware to see the triangle rotating on his center vertical axis.

The second glTranslate is useless.

Caution: 
glLoadIdentity, glTranslatef, glRotatef, glBegin, glVertex3f, glColor3f and  glEnd are deprecated since 2009 (OpenGL 3.1).